# How can I get the value of a parameter passed to a method in a custom rule in FxCop?

Tags: asp.net, fxcop

Due to certain reasons, in our ASP.NET web application, it is not recommended to use `Response.Redirect("something", True)`. It should be used with False for the `endResponse` parameter. We want to enforce this with a custom FxCop rule.
I've managed to find the usages of Response.Redirect, but now I want to find the value of the `endResponse` argument. How can I do this?

We're using the following code:

```
public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
{
    var method = member as Method;
    if (method != null)
    {
        foreach (var instruction in method.Instructions)
        {
            switch (instruction.OpCode)
            {
                case OpCode.Call:
                case OpCode.Callvirt:
                case OpCode.Newobj:
                    var call = (Method) instruction.Value;
                    if (call == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (call.Name.Name != "Redirect")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (call.Parameters.Count == 1)
                    {
                        //Redirect(url)
                        var resolution = GetResolution();
                        var problem = new Problem(resolution);
                        Problems.Add(problem);
                    }
                    if (call.Parameters.Count == 2)
                    {
                        VisitStatements(call.Body.Statements);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return Problems;
}

public override void VisitExpression(Expression expression)
{
    var methodCall = expression as MethodCall;
    if (methodCall == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var operand in methodCall.Operands)
    {
        if (operand.Type.Name.Name == "Int16" || operand.Type.Name.Name == "Int32" || operand.Type.Name.Name == "Int64")
        {
            var literal = operand as Literal;
            if (literal != null && literal.Value is int)
            {
                var literalValue = (int)literal.Value;
                if (literalValue == 1)
                {
                    var resolution = GetResolution();
                    var problem = new Problem(resolution);
                    Problems.Add(problem);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've used [Introspector](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/introspector.html) and thought the `endResponse` parameter was an integer behind the scenes, but I'm not so sure anymore. Anyway, there don't seem to be any booleans in the `methodCall.Operands`.

Has anyone ever had a similar situation, where you need to check the actual value of a parameter that's passed to a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the parameter type is actually a System.Boolean, the FxCop IL parser is treating it as an integer.  Here's a simplified version of the rule that should work (assuming you want non-literal endResponse values to trigger a rule violation):

```
    public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
    {
        Method method = member as Method;
        if (method != null)
        {
            this.Visit(method.Body);
        }

        return this.Problems;
    }

    public override void VisitMethodCall(MethodCall call)
    {
        base.VisitMethodCall(call);

        Method targetMethod = (Method)((MemberBinding)call.Callee).BoundMember;
        if (targetMethod.DeclaringType.FullName.Equals("System.Web.HttpResponse", StringComparison.Ordinal) &&
            targetMethod.Name.Name.Equals("Redirect", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            bool callIsAcceptable = false;

            if (targetMethod.Parameters.Count == 2)
            {
                Expression endResponseOperand = call.Operands[1];
                if (endResponseOperand.NodeType == NodeType.Literal)
                {
                    if ((int)((Literal)endResponseOperand).Value == 1)
                    {
                        callIsAcceptable = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!callIsAcceptable)
            {
                this.Problems.Add(new Problem(this.GetResolution(), call));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I changed it to .Value == 0 because that's what we want. Also, I noticed that if there are two vioaltions to this rule in one method, both are added to the Problems collection, but only one shows in FxCop. If I then fix the first violation, the second one will show when I do a new analysis.
Other than that, it works, and we can use this code. Thanks.

Comment: The FxCop UI application groups violations by their target.  If look at the issues list for a message, you'll see the full list of violations.

Comment: Strange, I had this problem in a test project. When putting the code in the real project, I get all the correct errors. Thanks for all the help anyway!